# Problem after NVIDIA GT520M driver install

Tags: nvidia, ubuntu-netbook, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Today I tried to install the Nvidia driver ( from their website) for my Nvidia GT520M on my 11.10 ubuntu. 
I have stop lightdm so as to not have the " Xserver problem message" and the install was good but now when I restart my laptop, i don't have the normal colors and cases to put my password but only text in black and white.. like "

```
*Starting anac(h)ronistic cron anacron [OK]
*Starting deferred execution scheduler atd [OK]
*Starting periodic command scheduler crond [OK]
*Checking battery state... [OK]
*Running local boot scripts (/etc/rc.local) [OK] "
```

Could anyone help me please?

EDIT :
Thank you for your link !

But now I make a " sudo sh NVIDIA.run --uninstall" so as to uninstall the driver I installed today and the problem is that I don't have anything after the violet page with " UBUNTU" and the orange&white points.. I only have a blackscreen & ctrl+alt+fX doesnt work

Do anyone have an idea to fix it or am I obliged to reinstall ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just went to Additional Drivers and that fixed it and installed the Nvidia drivers.